# .map Issue not showing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

```
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Chocotorta",
    desciption: "Torta de chocolate y dulce de leche",
    price: "$2,40",
    imgDesc: "",
    imgUrl: ""
  }
];

const Item = (prod) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Card key={prod.id}>
        <CardImg alt={prod.imgDesc} src={prod.imgUrl} top width="100%" />
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle tag="h5">{prod.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle className="mb-2 text-muted" tag="h6">
            {prod.price}
          </CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>{prod.desciption}</CardText>
          <Button>Mostrar detalle</Button>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

return (
  <>
    {loading ? (
      <div style={spinnerStyle}>
        <Spinner color="primary" size="">
          .
        </Spinner>
      </div>
    ) : (
      products.map((prod) => <Item prod={products} />)
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Please include some more detail on what you're trying to achieve and what's not working, as the question as-asked doesn't provide this detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rename the `map` element to `itemProd` or something, `prod` is used a lot in this snippet. That being said, you aren't passing anything into the `<Item />`, your snippet should be something like:

```
products.map((itemProd) => <Item prod={itemProd} />)
```

Edit: actually it looks like you also need to do this as well:

```
const Item = ({prod}) => {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I guess this is what you are looking for

```
export const products = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Chocotorta",
        desciption: "Torta de chocolate y dulce de leche",
        price: "$2,40",
        imgDesc: "",
        imgUrl: ""
      }
    ];
    
    const Item = ({prod}) => {
      return (
        <>
          <Card>
            <CardImg alt={prod.imgDesc} src={prod.imgUrl} top width="100%" />
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle tag="h5">{prod.title}</CardTitle>
              <CardSubtitle className="mb-2 text-muted" tag="h6">
                {prod.price}
              </CardSubtitle>
              <CardText>{prod.desciption}</CardText>
              <Button>Mostrar detalle</Button>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    return (
      <>
        {loading ? (
          <div style={spinnerStyle}>
            <Spinner color="primary" size="">
              .
            </Spinner>
          </div>
        ) : (
          products.map((product) => <Item prod={product} key={product.id} />)
        )}
      </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const items =
    products.map((item) => {
        return (<Item prod={item} key={item.id} />)
    })
;
```

And put the variable in your return like this:

```
 {items}
```